# Get variables that have been created inside a function

Tags: r, function, variables, extract

I have created a function (which is quite long) that I have saved in a .txt file.
It works well (I use source(<  >) to access it).
My problem is that I have created a few variables in that function 
ie:

```
myfun<-function(a,b) {
Var1=....
Var2=Var1 + ..
}
```

Now I want to get those variables.
When I include `return()` inside the function, its fine: the value comes up on the screen, but when I type Var1 **outside** the function, I have an error message "the object cannot be found".
I am new to R, but I was thinking it might be because "myfun" operates in a different envrionment than the global one, but when I did

```
environment()
environment: R_GlobalEnv>
environment(myfun1)
environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

It seems to me the problem is elsewhere...

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: `return` doesn't `assign` your `var1` object, you need to do that yourself. E.g. if `myfun` `returns` an object internal to your function called `var1` you need to do `var1 <- myfun(a,b)` to save this to your global environment.

Comment: Additionally if you want to return multiple functions you can return a list `return(list(var1=var1,var2=var2))`. when calling this e.g. `var1 <- myfun(a,b)` then the two variables will be var1$var1 and var1$var2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it in a nice way, write a class and than provide a print method. Within this class it is possible to return variables invisible. A nice book which covers such topics is ["The Art of R programming"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593273843).

An easy fix would be save each variable you need later on an list and than return a list
(as Peter pointed out):

```
return(list(VAR1=VAR1, .....))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. However, it still doesn"t work.. Maybe I misunderstood your answers, but I edited my text file, and added the following line: LISTE<-(list(var1,var2)) and print(LISTE) in the function. When I execute myfun in my program, "LISTE" come up, but stil, when I call LISTE in the program itself (and not in the function) the object cannot be found....) Any idea why ?

Comment: OK it's working now, I guess I was not really familiar with the idea of "slots" in lists.. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I realize this answer is more than 3 years old but I believe the option you are looking for is as follows:

```
myfun <- function(a,b) {
  Var1 = (a + b) / 2   # do whatever logic you have to do here...
  Var2 <<- Var1 + a    # then output result to Global Environment with the "<<-" object.  
}
```

The double "<<-" assignment operator will output "Var2" to the global environment and you can then use or reference it however you like without having to use "return()" inside your function.

Comment: What if you can't change the function? Is it correct to say it is impossible?

Comment: @stallingOne - It's a bit difficult to give an answer on this unless you give more context around your question. Why are you not able to change the function? Also, the scenario you posed seems somewhat outside the scope of the original question to which this thread belongs. It is `assumed that you are able to modify the function` - which is the scope of the original question.